# What was Mysterio's plan?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

I'm a little confused about Mysterio's plan in *Spider-Man: Far From Home.*

It occurred to me at about the two-thirds mark that it's very similar to Syndrome's plan in *The Incredibles.*  However, Syndrome did it out of spite in order to (eventually) render Supers superfluous.  But

> Mysterio wanted to become an Avenger

which doesn't make a lot of sense because

> his powers are illusory; once the Avengers faced a real threat, he'd be incapable of contributing.

Can someone explain Mysterio's plan?

Comment: I don’t think he wanted to be an Avenger. He wanted to be a superhero who would be a replacement to all the Avengers combined.

Comment: @Shreedhar exactly, he wanted to be a new super hero so people would forget the Avengers and so Iron Man.

Comment: @Shreedhar - Big ambitions for a person without any real powers.

Comment: Same question on movies.se https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101930/whats-becks-ultimate-plan/101970#101970

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Beck wants to become the new version of the Avengers, he wants to displace them and gain the power and glory that comes with it. He mainly wants the recognition and the power for it... **fame and glory**, that’s pretty much it.

They also have a smaller goal during the film which is that they want to gain control of their inventions again by coercing Peter into giving Beck the EDITH glasses. That appears to be a lot of their main initial reasonings. However, they are also brought together through their joint hatred for Tony Stark. So they are then trying to get people to forget about Tony and his sacrifice and worship Mysterio instead. Displace his memory because they don’t want him remembered so they need someone new to take that place.

That is part of the reason why Beck works with Peter to get him to go back to a normal life and why he reveals him at the end. Peter is the new Iron Man and his protégée so getting him to give it up further removes Iron Man from people’s memories.

> **Quentin Beck:** You’re right, you may not be ready, but this is my responsibility.
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: Far From Home*</sub>

Lastly, you ask how would he defend against a real threat? Well assuming he would try and fight it depending on its nature the illusions would be very effective. Remember how effective they were against Peter initially.

Also if the plan went to plan he would have had full control of EDITH and the Stark security network. There’s massive power to that, that he would be able to leverage to fight threats. The illusion tech also has a lot of extra functions that could be useful here and there.

Comment: Like the drones that actually could attack and harm stuff. That still might be useful in a real fight.

Comment: @Chipster: Beck is a nerd, and like all nerds in 2019, he knows in his heart that the solution to every problem is drones.

Comment: For such a smart guy, this seems like a really dumb plan.  Borderline suicidal.  Real "Avengers-level threats" have shown up on Earth at least three times; I guess he thinks that either a) he doesn't have to worry about any others, or b) he can take them on by himself.  Either one seems incredibly stupid.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet Not exactly stupid when he never has to put himself in harms way and will still be quite the opponent.

Comment: Yeah, his goal was to become the new Iron Man. He already gained access to all of the abilities under the control of EDITH (massive cloaked drone army, unfettered IT access). The next step would have given him access to SHIELD's resources. Who knows, he may have even have planned to eventually control Tony's Iron Man suits. All of this he can do remotely without ever actually having to be in harm's way. That's pretty powerful.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Every time Tony faced a threat at that level, he was outmatched and needed a great deal of help to survive (or less charitably, was saved by the plot). Imagine Mysterio's drones tickling Thanos as he just ignored them. Imagine Hela shredding them with a storm of knives. Imagine Dormammu not even noticing them. Imagine Ultron turning them against Beck himself! Beck is woefully incapable of replacing all of the Avengers, and he should have known that. Especially since his image requires him to be on the front lines.

Comment: Even someone with more limited powers could be hard for him to deal with. Anyone with electrical abilities or technical interfacing powers is capable of taking out a whole swarm of his drones if they strike first. Anyone who can teleport or is extremely fast will be very hard to deal with, since Beck himself is quite vulnerable. For that matter, he would have trouble with any large group of opponents, since he only has so many drones.

Comment: Also, let's face it, the way technology is presented in the MCU is as a matter of individual genius. Beck is not Tony, and never will be. He does not have the ability to come up with some new gadget on the spur of the moment to adapt to threats. Anything outside of his comfort zone would be very dangerous.